# Facebook application visible to admin

Tags: php, facebook

I'm developing a facebook application.It will have many links,i've to make few links only visible to admins of the page.

Should i use FQL to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use FQL see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_admin/